# In AngularJS, is it possible to filter inside of a specific element of an array using only a view?

Tags: angularjs

I've got some data like this:

```
people = [
    {
        names: [
            {first: "Joe", last: "Smith"}, 
            {first: "Joseph", last: "Smith"}, 
            ...
        ]
    }, 
    ...
]
```

In other words, an array of objects with an array of names.  For example, a person could be called "Joe Smith" or "Joseph Smith".  How can I use a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) to only search the first element of names? IE: If I typed in "Jo" or "Smith" it would find the first person.  But, if I typed in "seph" it wouldn't.

I've been looking at the [examples on this page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter), but there isn't really an example of filtering inside arrays.  Here's what I've tried but it gives me an error:

```
<input ng-model="search.names[0].$">
```

> TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined

Comment: Have u tried just "search.names.$" ?

Comment: @FooL When I try that it "doesn't work".  As soon as I type into the input, all rows disappear.  They don't come back when I clear the text box either.  There's probably some error, but no error is reported in the JS console. **But more importantly, I don't think that could accomplish what I want.**  I only want to search `names[0]`.  I don't want to search every element in the `names` array.

Comment: Ah, I see. Perhaps you can create a new variable that looks like an array of hashes with the values: `var names0 = [{x:'foo'},{x:'bar'}]` and have search filter on that var instead `search.names0.$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working Code

Input HTML

`<input ng-model="searchTerm">`

Results

`<tr ng-repeat="p in people | filter:searchFunc">...</tr>`

Controller

```
$scope.searchFunc = function(person) {
    var firstPersonsName = [person.names[0]]; // Wrapping in array since the 'filter' $filter expects an array
    var matches = $filter('filter')(firstPersonsName, $scope.searchTerm); // Running firstPersonsName through filter searching for $scope.searchTerm
    return matches.length > 0;
}
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SjTdoEhNjdekJY9d8dq0?p=preview)

---

### Answer to the question in your title

I played around with `filter` and it doesn't seem like you can go beyond one level deep when specifying a pattern object for it e.g. `ng-model="search.names"` works but `ng-model="search.names.otherVal"` doesn't.

Also, even if `filter` supported going beyond one level deep, you still wouldn't be able to do `ng-model="search.names[0]"`. This is because `filter` expects the input to be an array, but the elements of your names array are all objects *e.g.* `people[0].names[0] == {first: "Joe", last: "Smith"}` so filtering will never work.

The only way to do what you are asking purely through the view and no extra code in your controller is to just create your own custom filter that handles your case.

Answer (score 1):

Would this do the trick?

Say that your input is

```
<input ng-model="search.name" type="text">
```

Then, you can display results like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people[0].names | filter: alias">...</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.alias = function (object) {
  if (object.first.match(new RegExp($scope.search.name))) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```